# A Contour Integral I

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration

What is the value of the integral
\begin{align}
\int_{-a}^{c} \sqrt{ \frac{a+x}{c-x} } \ \frac{dx}{(d-x)(x-b)} 
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

This integral simplifies if you first make a change of variable $$ \sqrt{ \frac{a+x}{c-x} }=u^2$$ that is to say $$x=\frac{c u^2-a}{u^2+1}$$ So $$I=\int \sqrt{ \frac{a+x}{c-x} } \ \frac{dx}{(d-x)(x-b)}=-\int \frac{2 u^2 (a+c)~~ du}{\left(u^2 (b-c)+a+b\right) \left(u^2 (d-c)+a+d\right)}$$ Using partial fractions, this leads to $$I=\int \frac{2 (a+b)}{(b-d) \left(u^2 (b-c)+a+b\right)}- \int \frac{2 (a+d)}{(b-d) \left(u^2 (d-c)+a+d\right)}$$ Using $u$ as variable, the bounds are $0$ and $\infty$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: How does this transformation remove the branch cut between $a$ and $c$?

Comment: I must confess that I just looked at the problem of the antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $a,c>0$, and $b$ and $d$ are not in the interval $[-a,c]$.

Use a branch of $f(z) = \sqrt{(a+z)/(c-z)}$ that is analytic away from that interval.
Compare the integral over a "dumbbell contour" that goes around the branch cut
with a large circular contour.  Note that the limit of $f(z)$ as you approach a point on the branch cut from above is $-$ the limit as you approach the same point from below.  Don't forget the poles at $b$ and $d$.